# Weird USB device shows up in logs

Tags: windows, usb, security, malware

From time to time I use usbdeview, a small tool to show installed usb drivers, to check on my PC if someone has plugged in a flash drive etc. while I was not attending the computer.

Anyway, couple days ago an interesting recor showed up: 
"Port_#0003.Hub_#0001   Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)"

weird thing is, this location seems to be an internal port (if something like this exists on a laptop?) and it is usually used by the wireless adapter as it seems.

Now the real question: Was this simply caused by the wireless device failing temporarily, or has someone plugged in a device into the PC? I tried to check the Windows Even Viewer for more information but nothing substantial came out of it. I think the location Port_#0003.Hub_#0001 could be a hint, since the two externally available usb ports seem to be labeled as Port_#0014 and Port_#0015 when something is plugged into them. 
I also think if this was an error, it could have been caused by a bluetooth mouse I've been using for a while, since the wireless card also packs bluetooth chip (as far as I can understand).

Anyway, has anyone else experienced something similar? Do the port locations indicated by the OS change, or are they fixed (eg. the Port_#0014 is the left side port, the 0003 is an internal port etc.) or are they interchangeable?

Also, the device manager doesn't show any unrecognized usb device errors and the mentioned, unknown usb device doesn't seem to be plugged in anymore, also it seems like it was only briefly connected anyway, since the last plugin and creation date seems to be the same (but this I think could be misleading?)

Any help is welcome!

Comment: The wireless device is typically PCI, not USB... Bluetooth, keyboard, and mouse can be USB though. Just stating the port and hub is not very informative, do you have anything else like the idVendor or idProduct values (this could nearly pinpoint the device)? If you only have the port and hub number, do you ever see anything connected to that port?

Comment: @acejavelin well, actually to that port only the said wireless device seems to be connected and nothing else. when I plug in anything else into the usb ports of the laptop, it shows up either as Port_#0014 or 15. The unknown device doesn't have any of that info. Only thing I got is this:

`Port_#0003.Hub_#0001 Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed) Unknown No No No No      0000 0002 0.00 00 00 00                   (Standard USB Host Controller)     Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed) 10.0.14393.0 BADDEVICE.Dev.NT usb.inf  SilentInstall, RawDeviceOK`

Comment: @acejavelin, if system says that "device descriptor failed", it means no VID/PID was received.

Comment: OP: can you try USBtreeview and establish correspondence between physical ports, internal ports, and USB port enumeration, with OS-based handles?

Comment: @AliChen this is the one from uwe sieber's site am I correct? What information should I look for specifically?

Comment: The USBview gives you physical tree of devices and physical ports. I don't know how windows assigns numbers to them. By experimenting with external ports, you can establish the mapping, some at least. Is there something ever attached to your Port.3 Hub.1 under normal conditions?

Comment: @AliChen thanks for the help so far, I'm using usbdeview tool to that same extend and it seems like there is nothing else ever attached to that port, other than the "Dell Wireless 1820A Bluetooth 4.1 LE". Whenever I plug in something into the other ports, they show up either as Port_#0014 or 15, I have one usb type c port, but I cannot test it since I have no usb type c cable/device at hand currently.

Comment: So, you do have an internal BT device attached to that particular USB port. A BT device is usually a separate RF processor with intelligence, so it is possible that some firmware glitch happens when BT was trying to scan its neighborhood, or something, so the USB interface has a hang for some time waiting for the BT processor to reboot. Or something to that extent.

Comment: @AliChen yes, something to that extend, at least as far as I can understand it too. The bluetooth mouse seems to be attached/used by that port (the same one as the wifi device) when it is on. Although I haven't been able to reproduce this, not even once. I think it happened in a way because I shut down the computer (or put it to sleep) and woke it back up when the device was no present.

Comment: @AliChen But as I've said, I haven't been able to reproduce it. The important thing for me here is: if this was not the doings of a super smart malware that somehow switched the used ports names etc, this (eg. a weird device showing up that seems to be only plugged in once and was unrecognized) is most likely a glitch, am I correct?

Comment: I think so. The indications are that the port #0003 died for some reason, and host tried to re-enumerate it, but the attempt was unsuccessful. If you can get some full log, there should be the another attempt, and it was OK.

Comment: @AliChen I tried to find may way around the Windows Event Viewer but not to much success, anyway I think I can call it a day for this, since neither malware/antivirus scan yielded any positives. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your device log here: `C:\Windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log`.

For more details use `PowerShell` and look at these registry entries:

```
$Path = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR\*\*'                              
Get-ItemProperty -Path $Path | Select-Object -Property FriendlyName, CompatibleIDs, Mfg
```